# How to get fields quantity_done and reserved_availability in Odoo17

Tags: odoo-17

Hello guys in odoo16 i can easy access fields quantity_done and reserved_availability but in odoo17 replaced so how can i access quantity_done and reserved_availability in odoo17

found in odoo 16 but not found in odoo17

```
quantity_done = fields.Float(
    'Quantity Done', compute='_quantity_done_compute', digits='Product Unit of Measure',
reserved_availability = fields.Float(
    'Quantity Reserved', compute='_compute_reserved_availability',
    digits='Product Unit of Measure',
    readonly=True, help='Quantity that has`your text` already been reserved for this move')
    inverse='_quantity_done_set', store=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [stock: quantity pocalypse](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/7dda6bb92715ea25b2818a62fec5e646f3678b81) commit

> Changes:
> Qty done and reserved qty are merged into a single column.
> A new checkbox on the move exists to mark it as picked or not
> Since the reservation always follow the quantity, it's now possible
> to have more reserved quantity than stock. However the system will
> never propose it and the inventory showing reserved > quantity should
> be a warning.
> The system should never modify a move that has been picked. We don't
> want to overide the user action.